# I would like to cut my input file to the output file in linux shell script

Tags: linux

I would like to cut my input file to the output file in Linux shell script.

Input file

```
ANI_NO;ANI_IDNO;BIRTH_D;SEX;SIRE_ANI.NO;SIRE_ANI_IDNO;DAM_ANI_NO;DAM_ANI_IDNO
17441163;BRMMGDP880054;19881019;M;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;3754140;BRMFGDP068100
19750215;BRMMGDP890040;19891006;M;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;11743556;BRMFGDP860019
24955692;BRMMGDP910080;19911212;M;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;12034096;BRMFGDP860029
18135053;BRMMGDP890008;19890216;M;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;10777720;BRMFGDP860009
22679344;BRMFGDP900019;19901023;F;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;13002167;BRMFGDP870007
23285273;BRMMGDP910005;19910125;M;12566287;BRMMAGG850096;14041693;BRMFGDP870010
```

Output file

```
ANI_IDNO;BIRTH_D;SEX;SIRE_ANI_IDNO;DAM_ANI_IDNO
BRMMGDP880054;19881019;M;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP068100
BRMMGDP890040;19891006;M;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP860019
BRMMGDP910080;19911212;M;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP860029
BRMMGDP890008;19890216;M;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP860009
BRMFGDP900019;19901023;F;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP870007
BRMMGDP910005;19910125;M;BRMMAGG850096;BRMFGDP870010
```

Comment: `man cut`, or `man awk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), specifying the **d**elimiter and the **f**ields you want:

```
cut -d';' -f2,3,4,6,8 input.file > output.file
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much